# Get the last id of a column in where/and clause mysql/sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys I want to get the last id of a column in where/and clause.

This is what I've tried:

```
 SELECT i.documentnumber, i.documentseq, i.transactiondate, v.vancode, i.itemcode, i.qty, i.amount, i.reason, i.posted, i.dateposted, i.unitprice
FROM intrans AS i
JOIN intrans_vancode AS v ON i.locationcode = v.vancode
WHERE posted = 0
ORDER BY v.id DESC
```

But I'm getting a group function error/issue.

Any ideas how to achieve what I want? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for the one record with the Max id, why not use a variable:

```
Declare @MaxID int
Set @MaxId = ( Select Max(id) From intrans_vancode )

Select 
    i.documentnumber, 
    i.documentseq, 
    i.transactiondate, 
    v.vancode,
    i.itemcode, 
    i.qty, 
    i.amount, 
    i.reason, 
    i.posted, 
    i.dateposted, 
    i.unitprice
FROM intrans AS i
    Join intrans_vancode v On i.locationcode = v.vancode
WHERE i.posted = 0 -- you didn't specify a prefix so I don't which table this column belongs to
AND v.id = @MaxID
```